# Login form not getting submitted(i.e not posting to endpoint)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

There's a html page(login.html) which has form whose end point is ./login and method is post.

In the server side index.js is the entry point for the website.

```
const express=require('express')
const path=require('path')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const login=require('./loginServer.js')

const app=express();
const port=3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public', 'index.html'));
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/login', login);


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Student', 'Teacher'],
    required: true
  },
  instituteName: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    // Add a regex pattern for email validation if needed
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
module.exports = User;

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); // Access form data
  const username = req.body.username;
  const category = req.body.category;
  const instituteName = req.body.schoolName;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  const userData = { username, category, instituteName, email, password };
  // console.log(userData);

  try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/manashealth");
    // Use await with insertMany to handle the promise
    await User.insertMany([userData]);

    console.log('User inserted successfully!');
    res.send('Welcome!!');
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 11000) {
      console.error('Duplicate key error:', error.errmsg);
      res.send(`Account with the email already exists.`);
    } else {
      // Handle other MongoDB errors
      console.error('MongoDB error:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error.');
    }
  }finally{
    await mongoose.disconnect();
    console.log('mongoose disconnected');
  }
});


app.listen(port,'::',()=>{
  console.log(`Server is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I wanted to write the code to handle the ./login in another file(loginServer.js). So I've used express.Router() to handle that end point in LloginServer.js and I've also exported it in the end of the file.

```
const express=require('express')
const path=require('path')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const User = require('./index.js')

const router=express.Router();

router.post('/login', async (req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  const credentials = {email, password};

  try{
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/manashealth");
    
    const findUser = await User.findOne({email})

    if(findUser){
      console.log(findUser);
      res.send('success');
    }else{
      console.log('user not found');
    }
  }catch (error) {
    console.error('Error finding user:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }finally{
    await mongoose.disconnect();
    console.log('mongoose disconnected');
  }
})
module.exports = router;
```

Now when i try to login(i.e. click on login) the form is not getting submitted(I think it's not posting).

I tried collect the data from the login.html page through a endpoint ./login, also I handle the endpoint in the backend.

When i run the loginServer.js code I'm encountering this error

> PS C:\Users\valli\Desktop\project school\manashealth> node "c:\Users\valli\Desktop\project school\manashealth\loginServer.js"
> c:\Users\valli\Desktop\project school\manashealth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469
> throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
> ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
at Function.use (c:\Users\valli\Desktop\project school\manashealth\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469:13)
at Function. (c:\Users\valli\Desktop\project school\manashealth\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:227:21)
at Array.forEach ()
at Function.use (c:\Users\valli\Desktop\project school\manashealth\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:224:7)
at Object. (c:\Users\valli\Desktop\project school\manashealth\index.js:18:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)

Node.js v21.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a routing issue. You are using the router with a `/login` path prefix

```
app.use('/login', login);
```

But you also added the `/login` path to the endpoint itself within the router

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res)=> {...});
```

That means that the real path of your endpoint is `/login/login`

To fix this you could:

- change the endpoint you are calling with your fetch method `fetch('/login/login')`
- change the post path to just a slash `router.post('/')`
- or what you probably want to do, remove additional path prefix from the router usage: `app.use(login);`

Comment: I'm also encountering this error when i run the loginServer.js file:
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')...

Even after changing the endpoint there's no change.

Comment: what's the line that throws this error? could you update the question? I cannot reproduce the issue with the code provided. if you exported the router and you are passing the imported router to app.use it should work

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question.

Comment: can you try logging the `login` variable and see what you get? It should be a router but it seems it's an object? Maybe try passing `login.default` instead?

Comment: Actually, the problem was with circular dependency also. I've imported index.js in loginServer.js and also loginServer.js into index.js which might have caused them to run in loop?
It's working now!